# What is a good balance in an MVC model to have efficient data access?

Tags: database, model-view-controller, architecture, orm, query-optimization

I am working on a few PHP projects that use MVC frameworks, and while they all have different ways of retrieving objects from the database, it always seems that nothing beats writing your SQL queries by hand as far as speed and cutting down on the number of queries.

For example, one of my web projects (written by a junior developer) executes over 100 queries just to load the home page.  The reason is that in one place, a method will load an object, but later on deeper in the code, it will load some other object(s) that are related to the first object.

This leads to the other part of the question which is what are people doing in situations where you have a table that in one part of the code only needs the values for a few columns, and another part needs something else?  Right now (in the same project), there is one get() method for each object, and it does a "SELECT *" (or lists all the columns in the table explicitly) so that anytime you need the object for any reason, you get the whole thing.

So, in other words, you hear all the talk about how SELECT * is bad, but if you try to use a ORM class that comes with the framework, it wants to do just that usually.  Are you stuck to choosing ORM with SELECT * vs writing the specific SQL queries by hand?  It just seems to me that we're stuck between convenience and efficiency, and if I hand write the queries, if I add a column, I'm most likely going to have to add it to several places in the code.

Sorry for the long question, but I'm explaining the background to get some mindsets from other developers rather than maybe a specific solution.  I know that we can always use something like Memcached, but I would rather optimize what we can before getting into that.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!  It pretty much confirmed what I was already thinking...the ORM's are not designed for speed, but for ease of use...like dumbing down "programming" lanuagues and hoping for better programmers because of it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, assuming you are proficient at SQL and schema design, there are very few instances where any abstraction layer that removes you from the SQL statements will exceed the efficiency of writing the SQL by hand. More often than not, you will end up with suboptimal data access.

There's no excuse for 100 queries just to generate one web page.

Second, if you are using the Object Oriented features of PHP, you will have good abstractions for collections of objects, and the kinds of extended properties that map to SQL joins. But the important thing to keep in mind is to write the best abstracted objects you can, without regard to SQL strategies.

When I write PHP code this way, I always find that I'm able to map the data requirements for each web page to very few, very efficient SQL queries if my schema is proper and my classes are proper. And not only that, but my experience is that this is the simplest and fastest way to implement. Putting framework stuff in the middle between PHP classes and a good solid thin DAL (note: NOT embedded SQL or dbms calls) is the best example I can think of to illustrate the concept of "leaky abstractions".

Answer (score 0):

I got a little lost with your question, but if you are looking for a way to do database access, you can do it couple of ways. Your MVC can use Zend framework that comes with database access abstractions, you can use that.

Also keep in mind that you should design your system well to ensure there is no contention in the database as your queries are all scattered across the php pages and may lock tables resulting in the overall web application deteriorating in performance and becoming slower over time.

That is why sometimes it is prefereable to use stored procedures as it is in one place and can be tuned when we need to, though other may argue that it is easier to debug if query statements are on the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

**No ORM framework will even get close to hand written SQL in terms of speed**, although 100 queries seem unrealistic (and maybe you are exaggerating a bit) even if you have the creator of the ORM framework writing the code, it will always be far from the speed of good old SQL.

My advice is, look at the whole picture not only speed:

- Does the framework improves code readability?
- Is your team comfortable with writing SQL and mixing it with code?
- Do you really understand how to optimize the framework queries? (I think a get() for each object is not the optimal way of retrieving them)
- Do the queries (after optimization) of the framework present a bottleneck?

I've never developed anything with PHP, but I think that you could mix both approaches (ORM and plain SQL), maybe after a **thorough profiling** of the app you can determine the real bottlenecks and **only then** replace that ORM code for hand written SQL (Usually in ruby you use ActiveRecord, then you profile the application with something as new relic and finally if you have a complicated AR query you replace that for some SQL)

Regads

Answer (score 0):

Trust your experience.

To not repeat yourself so much in the code you could write some simple model-functions with your own SQL. This is what I am doing all the time and I am happy with it.

Many of the "convenience" stuff was written for people who need magic because they cannot do it by hand or just don't have the experience.

And after all it's a question of style.

Don't hesitate to add your own layer or exchange or extend a given layer with your own stuff. Keep it clean and make a good design and some documentation so you feel home when you come back later.